# Add a date in header section in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9

I have a list of item in which date is also specified and I want that date in header section. And according to date it should be sorted.  If that date is of today then it should show 'Today' in header and if the date is of tomorrow  then it should show 'Tomorrow'. What should I do for this?
If anyone wants to help then I'll be thankfull to them.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. It's not clear what your problem is - is it that you don't know how to put a string in the header, or that you don't know how to format dates, or that you don't know how to identify "today" and "tomorrow"?

Comment: You got the correct point. I don't know the how to put a string in header. @Grimxn

Comment: After about 10 seconds of web search, I found this: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can do using two table view delegate methods

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

header view can show by custom view with label or you can add programmatically in viewforHeaderInSection method.

- To show data in sorted form you have to sort data by date before to show in table view..
- To show Today and tomorrow you can set text label by using condition if your indexed date - today date difference is zero you will set text "Today" if difference is 1 You will set "Tomorrow" otherwise set date to label text.